# FormatException Invalid HTTP header Flutter on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, http-headers

This code work's on Android device and emulator perfectly. On **iOS** emulator, doesn't work.

I try change String to lower case, remove spaces, etc, nothing resolve.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' show Client;
...
Map<String,String> headers = Map();
headers['device'] = 'appleiphonexʀ';//'Apple-iPhone-Xʀ'//'Apple_iPhone_Xʀ'//'Apple iPhone Xʀ'
...
var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
return await processResponse(response);
```

Throws Exception:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid HTTP header field value: "appleiphonexʀ"
  _HttpHeaders._validateValue (dart:_http/http_headers.dart:601:9)
  _HttpHeaders._addAll (dart:_http/http_headers.dart:65:18)
  _HttpHeaders.set (dart:_http/http_headers.dart:76:5)
  IOClient.send.<anonymous closure> (package:http/src/io_client.dart:42:27)
  __CompactLinkedCustomHashMap&_HashFieldBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
  IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:41:23)
 < asynchronous suspension>
  BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
 < asynchronous suspension>
  BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:54:7)
  NetworkProvider.post (package:PROJECTXX/src/models/resources/network_provider.dart:24:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Solved: [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297925/2767337)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last character in your header is the Unicode code point `hex 0280` aka `LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL R`. According to RFC 2616, HTTP headers must only include characters in ISO-8859-1, unless they are encoded in a MIME format, which might look like `=?UTF-8?Q?=E2=9C=B0?=`. Could you instead use lower or uppercase ASCII `R`?

Comment: Thx @Richard Heap, after remove last character works perfectly., the problem wasn´t iOS

Answer (score 2):

Follow [Richard Heap comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293628/formatexception-invalid-http-header-flutter-on-ios/56295438#56295438), the problem was the last character, this data came from lib **device_info: ^0.4.0+1**

```
final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
...
var device = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo.name;//Apple iPhone Xʀ
...
//the solution: remove non ascii chars and substitute for underline        
headers['device'] = device.replaceAll(new RegExp('[^\u0001-\u007F]'),'_');
```